# Python class creates attributes in order

Tags: python, class, attributes, class-method

I am hoping to do some calculation using class methods and create a new attribute for each function (create_d and create_e). It doesn't feel very elegant because one has to run create_d before create_e. Is there a better way to organize them?

```
new_obj = TestClass(a, b, c)
new_obj.create_d(data)
new_obj.create_e(data)

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

    def create_d(self, data):
        self._d = math(data, self._a, self._b)

    def create_e(self, data):
        self._e = more_math(data, self._d)
```

Comment: Why not pass `data` to `__init__` and assign the attributes in order there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment says, you can pass `data` as parameter

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, data):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c
        self._d = math(data, self._a, self._b)
        self._e = more_math(data, self._d)
```

Then to initialize:

```
new_obj = TestClass(a, b, c)
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't wanna carry `self._d` and `self._e` because their calculation is so expensive you can use `properties` as below:

```
@property
def create_d(self, data):
  return math(data, self._a, self._b)
    
@property
def create_(self, data):
  return more_math(data, self._d)
```

And then when you need the values just call the `properties`:

```
new_obj.create_d # return the calculation
```

Or if you're gonna use after just store it in a variable:

```
e = new_obj.create_e
```

You can check [this](https://pybit.es/property-decorator.html) out for more examples. Hope this can help you :)

Comment: sure, but what if calculating and storing d and e is very costly and I don't want to carry them for all instances until the user needs it? for example, in stats model after fitting the data with the basic parameters, one can decide if they want to calculate additional metrics such as loss function etc.

Comment: I just edited base on your comment, check if it works for you plz